# Laravel: should I use ('foo', $bar) or ('foo', '=', '$bar') to query the database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Using laravel eloquent or fluent I can query the database using ('foo', $bar) or ('foo', '=', '$bar')

For example:

```
$var = DB::table('users')->where('foo', $bar)->get();
```

vs

```
$var = DB::table('users')->where('foo', '=', $bar)->get();
```

As I understand it, both of these work, but my question is this:

**Should I use one over the other and why?**

For example, will I run into any problems with one that I would not with the other? Or is it safe to use either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same thing. From the Query Builder.php file:

```
    // If the given operator is not found in the list of valid operators we will
    // assume that the developer is just short-cutting the '=' operators and
    // we will set the operators to '=' and set the values appropriately.
```

So in other words - "=" is the default, and makes no difference from a Laravel perspective.

The only reason you might want to use the "=" is to make is easier to read for other developers who are browsing your code, since you have explicity stated "where foo equals boo"